# Why does Google show two different site names for my site?

Tags: google-search, search-results, title

I recently upgraded to https as well as being the victim of malware/hacking. If i now search for my site i get two different site titles from google for my homepage?

For example if i search for the exact name "getgeek.net" i get the Asian hacked title which hasn't dissapeared:

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=getgeek&oq=getgeek&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2j0j69i65j69i59.1752j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=getgeek.net

but if i search for "getgeek" i see the correct title:

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=getgeek&oq=getgeek&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2j0j69i65j69i59.1752j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Why would it do this and is there anyway to force it to refresh?

Comment: Your first results are HTTP and your second HTTPS. Make sure you redirect HTTP to HTTPS. You do not want your site found both ways in search. You will end up with a duplicate content issue. This will solve your problems, however, it can take months so be patient. Cheers!!

Comment: If you have HTTP redirected to HTTPS, you do not need a canonical tag from your HTTP pages to your HTTPS pages. This is assuming that the redirect works correctly. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

**Try this method might help to solve your problem,**

You need to add a canonical tag to your new website. Canonical is nothing but 'individual web page can load for multiple urls creates by own'.

You can avoid this by adding a canonical tag to your website which you need to avoid duplication.This is the code you need to add on your new updated website to avoid creating a different URL for your same content `<link rel=" canonical" href="http://example.com/blog" />` (those codes on your head section your updated website/web page).

Or this may be one of the reasons for getting the same page you haven't redirect your old http site to your new https. By using htaccess file you can redirect your old page to new page by adding a code in htaccess file.

Creating a htaccess file:

1. Create a empty text file using default notepad and save it as htaccess.txt.
2. Edit the content in text file for redirecting as  # This allows you to   redirect your entire website to any other domain
   **`Redirect 301 / http://mt-example.com/`**
3. If you want to redirect a particular homepage/index.html page use this code
   **`Redirect /index.html http://example.com/newdirectory/`**.
4. You can use this for http to https redirecting 
   `RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]`
5. Upload this file and rename it to `.htaccess`.

**NOTE: If your website is already attacked by malware after know that all your content and website are secure then redirect otherwise don't do this method use cononical tag to avoid duplication.**

Feel free to ask if you have any doubts I'm here to clarify...!!
Thankyou

Comment: Hi, So i already have step 4 in my .htaccess to redirect all http to https. Do i need to include step 2 at all?
Also i am slightly confused by the canonical? Will adding the canonical link this tell Google to only list my site once? Or is my .htaccess redirecting to https from http sufficient for this?
Thanks

Comment: @Olly Use canonical tag also it will avoid your future duplication for your site and in ht access you need to **mainly implement the step4 **and step2 is optional one try the step4 once if your problem won't solve ...

I think this might be helpful for you if you have any doubts let me know...